# Find the norm of the linear operator $Ax=t^2x(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, bounded-variation

How do I find the norm of this linear operator : $Ax=t^2x(t)$  where $x(t)$ is from $C[a,b]$.

I tried to show that $A$ is  continuous. Here what I did:

let's take $x_0(t)$  from $C[a,b]$.

For any $\epsilon>0$  there is $\delta>0$  that $||x(t)-x_0(t)||<\delta$.

$||Ax-Ax_0||= ||t^2x(t)-t^2x_0(t)||\leq\ t^2||x(t)-x_0(t)||<t^2\delta<\epsilon $

if we take $\delta<\epsilon/t^2$  Operator $A$ will be continuous, so It'll be bounded.

To find the norm I took $x\ne0$ from $C[a,b]$:

$||A||=sup||Ax||/||x|| = sup||t^2(x/||x||)|| = b^2$

Is this correct proof? Am I right?

Comment: What norm are you applying?

Comment: Any norm of linear operator

Comment: But that's defined in terms of the norm on the domain and the norm on the range. You need a norm for $C [a, b]$.

Comment: Norm in $C[a,b]$ is $||Ax||=max|Ax|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but not the reasoning. The norm on $C[a,b]$ is $\|x\|=\max_{a\le t\le b}|x(t)|$. Then
$$
\|A\,x\|=\max_{a\le t\le b}|t^2\,x(t)|\le b^2\,\|x\|.
$$
This shows that $\|A\|\le b^2$. To show that $\|A\|=b^2$ pick the constant function $x(t)=1$. Then $\|x\|=1$ and $\|A\,x\|=\max_{a\le t\le b}t^2=b^2$.

Comment: thank you. but anyway I have to show that the operator is continuous to state that it is bounded and after to find its norm, isn't it?

Comment: For linear operators boundedness is equivalent to continuity.

Comment: Slight nitpick: this assumes $a^2 \leq b^2$. (Consider, e.g., $a = -5$, $b = 2$).